# Calling Laravel Routes hosted on AWS Lambda using AWS API Gateway

Tags: php, laravel, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to host a laravel application on aws lambda and call it's routes using aws api gateway. The application is basically a web crawler which fetches web pages from rss feeds.

When I make a call to a laravel route using the url generated by api gateway, laravel redirects the request to '/home' path. However, when I test it on ec2 instance using "node debug" , it works like a charm. Below are the details of the steps I followed.

I followed a fantastic blog written by [Chris White](https://cwhite.me/hosting-a-laravel-application-on-aws-lambda/) for hosting a laravel application on aws lambda.

**Steps:**

1. Generating a PHP CGI Binary

   I used  "amzn-ami-hvm-2016.03.3.x86_64-gp2" ec2 instance to build my php-cgi binary file

> ./configure --prefix=/tmp/php-7.0.11/compiled/ --without-pear
>   --enable-shared=no --enable-static=yes --enable-phar --enable-json --disable-all --with-openssl --with-curl --enable-libxml --enable-simplexml --enable-xml --with-mhash --with-gd --enable-exif --with-freetype-dir --enable-mbstring --enable-sockets --enable-pdo --with-pdo-mysql --enable-tokenizer --enable-session --enable-filter

2. NodeJS Lambda function to spawn PHP CGI process - **php.js** file

```js
process.env['PATH'] = process.env['PATH'] + ':' + process.env['LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT'];

var parser = require('http-string-parser');
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
exports.handler = function(event, context) {

  var requestMethod = event.httpMethod || 'GET';
  var serverName = event.headers ? event.headers.Host : '';
  var requestUri = event.path || '';
  var headers = {};

  if (event.headers) {
    Object.keys(event.headers).map(function(key) {
      headers['HTTP_' + key.toUpperCase()] = event.headers[key];
    });
  }

  var request_env = Object.assign({
    REDIRECT_STATUS: 1,
    REQUEST_METHOD: requestMethod,
    SCRIPT_FILENAME: 'api/public/index.php',
    SCRIPT_NAME: '/index.php',
    PATH_INFO: '/',
    SERVER_NAME: serverName,
    SERVER_PROTOCOL: 'HTTP/1.1',
    REQUEST_URI: requestUri
  }, headers);

  var php = spawn('./php-cgi', ['api/public/index.php'], {
    env: request_env
  });

  var response = '';

  php.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    response += data.toString('utf-8');
  });

  php.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log("STDERR: " + data.toString());
  });

  php.on('close', function(code) {

    var parsedResponse = parser.parseResponse(response);
    context.succeed({
      isBase64Encoded: false,
      statusCode: parsedResponse.statusCode || 200,
      headers: parsedResponse.headers,
      body: parsedResponse.body
    });

  });

}
```

3. Prepare AWS Lambda bundle

   The directory structure of my **HelloLambda.zip** bundle is

├── api

├── node_modules

├── php-cgi

└── php.js

The api folder consists of my laravel application.

4. API Gateway - I created a api gateway for my HelloLambda function. The api has league & channel as path parameters. The GET method uses lambda proxy integration. The api shows following url in stages view

> https://***.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/HelloLambda/espnheadlinesimage/{league}/{channel}

[api-gateway-screenshot.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pHIb.jpg)

5. Make a GET request to api providing the league and channel parameter.

> https://***.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/HelloLambda/espnheadlinesimage/nhl/28

When I make this get request, the browser shows a message

> Redirecting to http://***.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/home

My laravel routes.php file consists of below route

```
Route::get('espnheadlinesimage/{league}/{channel}', 'EspnController@headlinesimage');
```

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

Here's the console output of content of my event object in my test API call

```
{
    "resource": "/HelloLambda/espnheadlinesimage/{league}/{channel}",
    "path": "/HelloLambda/espnheadlinesimage/nhl/48",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,hi;q=0.4",
        "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
        "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
        "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "IN",
        "Host": "x7pdbfnzsg.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36",
        "Via": "2.0 0e9493f2bcf9035541b227fce2ae5798.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)",
        "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "93vabUcIQzqON2X5ive3a0nHmqcO47wFzNEBR0SMs39Wo1qlNK9bIA==",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-592e3ff4-132417a71f64bb62205997f7",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "103.243.10.67, 54.182.231.71",
        "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    },
    "queryStringParameters": null,
    "pathParameters": {
        "channel": "48",
        "league": "nhl"
    },
    "stageVariables": null,
    "requestContext": {
        "path": "/prod/HelloLambda/espnheadlinesimage/nhl/48",
        "accountId": "729779362209",
        "resourceId": "kbrsfu",
        "stage": "prod",
        "requestId": "bd922c44-45b5-11e7-81ca-777f94f39a98",
        "identity": {
            "cognitoIdentityPoolId": null,
            "accountId": null,
            "cognitoIdentityId": null,
            "caller": null,
            "apiKey": "",
            "sourceIp": "103.243.10.67",
            "accessKey": null,
            "cognitoAuthenticationType": null,
            "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": null,
            "userArn": null,
            "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36",
            "user": null
        },
        "resourcePath": "/HelloLambda/espnheadlinesimage/{league}/{channel}",
        "httpMethod": "GET",
        "apiId": "x7pdbfnzsg"
    },
    "body": null,
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is resolved as suggested by [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5679071/jack-kohn-aws).

The issue was that the API url being generated by API Gateway was

> /HelloLambda/espnheadlinesimage/{league}/{channel}

However the route in my Laravel routes file was

> /espnheadlinesimage/{league}/{channel}

My misconception was that the base url of for the lambda function is

> https://***.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/HelloLambda/

and I should add route after this path to my laravel routes file, i.e.,

> /espnheadlinesimage/{league}/{channel}

However, the path in my route file should include '/HelloLambda' ,i.e., it should be

> /HelloLambda/espnheadlinesimage/{league}/{channel}

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know anything about laravel but you have configured a route for `espnheadlinesimage/....` but you are actually calling the route `HelloLambda/espnheadlinesimage/{league}/{channel}` via API GW. The value of `requestUri` (and `event.path`) in the Lambda function will be `HelloLambda/espnheadlinesimage/nhl/28` in your test API call.

Comment: Thanks for a prompt reply. You are right, my requestUri is infact `/HelloLambda/espnheadlinesimage/nhl/28` in my test API call. I have edited the question with contents of my request API call event object.

Comment: Yeah so I'm saying, should that match the 'route' in laravel in this line? Route::get('espnheadlinesimage/{league}/{channel}', 'EspnController@headlinesimage');

Comment: Yes, it should match this route in laravel and the 'EspnController' should perform the function 'headlinesimage' with parameters 'nhl' and '28'  but I can't figure out why laravel is redirecting to '/home' instead.

Comment: I was thinking laravel is redirecting to `/home` because it doesn't recognize the route you are giving it which is `HelloLambda/espnheadlinesimage/nhl/28` rather than the one that you've configured `espnheadlinesimage/nhl/28`

Comment: I tried this and now it works. A silly mistake ! Thanks Jack !